What does psychoactive mean?
Al Jazeera has an article about cannabis cultivation in Pakistan. It says:

Unlike tetrahydrocannabinol (THC), the primary psychoactive compound in the cannabis plant that gives users a high, CBD is not psychoactive and believed to have therapeutic effects. It is increasingly prescribed by doctors to help with anxiety, chronic and acute pain, and other medical conditions.

What does psychoactive mean?  I would have thought something used to treat anxiety would be psychoactive, so this makes me wonder what this word means.
Wiki has the definition:

A psychoactive drug, psychopharmaceutical, psychoactive agent, or psychotropic drug is a chemical substance that changes the function of the nervous system and results in alterations of perception, mood, cognition, and behavior.

It would seem that any pharmaceutical that improves anxiety would fit this definition as well as any illegal drug, as they alter perception, mood, cognition, and behavior so it seems there is another definition that is been used here.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychoactive_drug

@KillingTime Under that definition CBD is psychoactive, which AJ seems to be saying is not the case.

Whether or not CBD is psychoactive is best answered by medical scientists rather than linguists.

It does not seem medically contentious that "help with anxiety" is an alteration of mood.

This is a valid and interesting question. I think psychoactive is normally given in a context of altering the conscious experience from normal to abnormal. Removing anxiety flips that around, though we wouldn't necessarily call something that produces anxiety psychoactive. I think there difference is that psychoactive implies a temporary and acute modification of perception, mood, cognition, or behavior. I'm left with little more than "you'll know it when you feel it".

@jimm101 "altering the conscious experience from normal to abnormal" I do not think it would be contentious to call morphine psychoactive, even when used to remove the "abnormal" sensation of post operative pain.

It's a scientific question about the effects of a drug, so it's better asked somewhere else, such as the psychology and neuroscience SE https://psychology.stackexchange.com/

@User65535 No, that's not correct: morphine is both an analgesic and a psychoactive drug. Aspirin is an analgesic and is not psychoactive (at normal doses). In a word, a psychoactive drug is an intoxicant. I think you'll find a circular definition in any dictionary, that being intoxicated means being under the influence of drugs. A description of red to a blind man will always come up short. The same may apply here to intoxicated, which is the crux of the matter.

In case this doesn't get reopened... 'psychoactive' refers to more hallucinatory things or at least making things happen in your brain out of the ordinary, not just -any- change to the brain (which might include reducing anxiety). Or, if this makes sense, there are further restrictions on the definition of 'psychoactive' such that it does not include anxiety (and most other mental difficulties).
